# How to resolve current HTTP request information from business logic library

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm trying to build an Azure function.
This function will use my current business logic library,

for example:

```
Users.Add(new User() { Name = "Test" } );
```

Users.Add() has internal exception handling, it will be caught here:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logs.Write(ex);
}
```

While "Logs" in turn will try to resolve the current HTTP request information; IP Address, HTTP headers etc. This is a typical logger behavior and a very logical one, trying to grab a snapshot of the current session for later investigation.

Besides the obvious and very ugly way of transferring the **httpRequestMessage** all the way down to business logic and then to "system" methods such as "Logs", messing up the entire code base, is there any nicer way?

I mean, calling

```
Users.Add(new User(), httpRequestMessage)
```

and adding **httpRequestMessage** to each and every business logic method (thousands of them) is extremely stupid and quite a code mess. It also has zero relevancy to the self explanatory naming, meaning and concept of "Users.Add".

Thanks

Comment: What are you using for logging? This is probably going to be heavily dependent on your logging library of choice. (The built-in stuff won't cut it, but they're in the process of updating that.) I do something similar with Serilog with an enricher but the process is still a little clumsy.

Comment: I'm actually using my own logging library which writes to a remote DB and falls back to a file.

Comment: Are you mean that you handle the exceptions via `try-catch` under your every business logic method? When working with azure function, I assumed that you could throw the exception instead of internal exception handling, then provide a new method overloading for `Logs.Write`, then manually capture the relevant business logic method exception in your function code.

Comment: I want to use the same business logic libraries ("Users.Add()") for Azure Functions and other console/service/web applications. Therefor I can't and don't want to fork the business logic to Functions and "the rest".